# I am not able to build this layout with Material UI in REACT

Tags: reactjs, layout, material-ui

[I am not able to code the middle layout which is highlighted in pink circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdETI.jpg)

[Layout I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6w6Rb.jpg)

I want to make this layout in materialUi react

Comment: What is your problem? You need to be more specific and show code. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about what you are asking, but I hope this will help you

there are different ways to do what you are trying to do, but I think it is important to maintain the correct grid order to do it.

Inside the pink circle seems to me that you are forgetting to wrap the card inside a grid item component, which would give you the possibility to align the cards in the way that you want.

I did a super easy example to better explain my point:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-6ylvv

Inside the container you can also decide to align with direction="column" and using xs={6}.. this is up to you, in the Material-UI documentation you can find different ways, I suggest you to spend more time in it and remember always to use item inside the container